# How to decode the unicode string starting with "%u" (percent symbol + u) in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding

I get some HTML code like the following:

```
<new>8003,%u767E%u5723%u5E97,113734,%u4E50%u4E8B%u542E%u6307%u7EA2%u70E7%u8089%u5473,6924743915824,%u7F50,104g,3,21.57,-2.16,0,%u4E50%u4E8B,1</new>
```

I know I can find and replace all the "%u" with "/u" in Notepad++, and then paste it into Python console to let it display correctly in Chinese characters. But how can I do it automatically in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your input string contains "percent-u" encoded chracters, we can find and decode them with a regex replace and a callback function.

Percent-u encoding represents a Unicode code point as four hexadecimal digits: `%u767E` ⇒ `767E` ⇒ codepoint 30334 ⇒ 百.

```
import re

def hex_to_char(hex_str):
    """ converts a single hex-encoded character 'FFFF' into the corresponding real character """
    return chr(int(hex_str, 16))

s = "<new>8003,%u767E%u5723%u5E97,113734,%u4E50%u4E8B%u542E%u6307%u7EA2%u70E7%u8089%u5473,6924743915824,%u7F50,104g,3,21.57,-2.16,0,%u4E50%u4E8B,1</new>"

percent_u = re.compile(r"%u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})")

decoded = percent_u.sub(lambda m: hex_to_char(m.group(1)), s)

print(decoded)
```

which prints

```
<new>8003,百圣店,113734,乐事吮指红烧肉味,6924743915824,罐,104g,3,21.57,-2.16,0,乐事,1</new>
```