# Python produces kysl� instead of kyslá

Tags: python-3.x, corruption

I have an HTML file `org22.htm` which contains a JavaScript section that goes like this (the code repeats as it fills the array `I`):

```
I = new Array();

I[0] = new Array();
I[0][1] = new Array();
I[0][1][0] = new Array();
I[0][1][0][0] = '\u006A\u0061\u0064\u0072\u006F';
I[0][1][1] = new Array();
I[0][1][1][0]='\u004A\u0061\u0064\u0072\u006F';
I[0][2]='';

I[1] = new Array();
I[1][1] = new Array();
I[1][1][0] = new Array();
I[1][1][0][0] = '\u0047\u0075\u0074\u0065\u006E\u0062\u0065\u0072\u0067\u006F\u0076\u0061';
I[1][1][1] = new Array();
I[1][1][1][0]='\u0067\u0075\u0074\u0065\u006E\u0062\u0065\u0072\u0067\u006F\u0076\u0061';
I[1][1][2] = new Array();
I[1][1][2][0]='\u0047\u0075\u0074\u0065\u006E\u0062\u0065\u0072\u0067\u006F\u0076\u0061\u0020\u0070\u006C\u006F\u0063\u0068\u0061';
I[1][1][3] = new Array();
I[1][1][3][0]='\u0067\u0075\u0074\u0065\u006E\u0062\u0065\u0072\u0067\u006F\u0076\u0061\u0020\u0070\u006C\u006F\u0063\u0068\u0061';
I[1][2]='';
```

I'm trying with Python code to get the actual value of the strings, i.e. `'\u0047\u0075\u0074\u0065\u006E\u0062\u0065\u0072\u0067\u006F\u0076\u0061'` -> `'Gutenbergova'`, but that does seem to work correctly.

With accented characters I always get something like `kysl�` instead of the wanted `kyslá`.

Here is my current full code:

```
import re

with open("org22.htm","r") as f:
    data = f.read()

start = "I = new Array();"
end = "State = new Array();"
s = data
array_r = s[s.find(start)+len(start):s.rfind(end)]
array_r = array_r.split("\n")
count, res = 0, []
for line in array_r:
    compare = "I["+str(count)+"][1][0][0] ="
    if compare in line:
            res.append(line)
            count += 1

f = open("dump.TXT","w+")
f.close()
f = open("dump.TXT","a")
for i in res:
    unic = i.split("'")[-2]
    trans = bytes(unic,"utf-8").decode('unicode-escape') + "\n"
    trans = trans.encode('utf-8').decode('utf8')
    f.write(trans)

f.close()
```

Comment: `unic = \\u006A\\u0061\\u0064\\u0072\\u006F` is not valid Python code. You've got to be precise if you want this question to go anywhere. Mentioning where the value of `unic` comes from (Read from a database? From a web server? A file maybe? how?) will also help.

Comment: Where does `org22.htm` come from? Did you write/create it? Does it look right when you load it in a browser?

Comment: its in the question: It reads Hot Potatoes 7 JCloze excercise

Comment: ... It's probably not uft-8 but some other codec...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your encoding and decoding of strings is necessary in the first place.

**Never** open text files without explicitly specifying the file's encoding. It's a simple, universal rule. If *you* don't know the encoding of the files you're reading (or writing) and leave Python to use whatever default it feels like using, all bets are off.

HTML files tend to be UTF-8 encoded. The other likely candidate is Windows-1252 (`cp1252`). But in fact it depends on how the file was created, so you have to check.

This should be pretty close to what you had in mind. No part of this code deals with encoding any strings - `open()` does that for you.

```
with open("org22.htm", "r", encoding="utf8") as infile:
    html = infile.read()

start = "I = new Array();"
end = "State = new Array();"
pos1 = html.find(start) + len(start)
pos2 = html.rfind(end)

lines = html[pos1:pos2].splitlines()

with open("dump.txt", "w", encoding="utf8") as outfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if f"I[{i}][1][0][0] =" in line:
            data = line.split("'")[-2]
            outfile.write(data + "\n")
```

Comment: data is not defined

Comment: lines = data[pos1:pos2].splitlines()
NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: Hello, i am sorry but your code produces an empty file

Comment: That was a typo. You did not exactly give me enough info to write code that I can test. But what's more important: Don't copy and paste my code. Read it, and do *what it means*.

Comment: Looks like I knew what i was doing with that encoding since org22.htm has the values i am reading in this format: \\u006A\\u0061\\u0064\\u0072\\u006F

Comment: link to org22.htm so you have enough info: https://anonfile.com/p9N4E3y7o2/org22_htm

Comment: Aha, that should have been in the question all along. And really, I've been trying to get this info out of you for an hour now.

Comment: I dont see why it matters, what i imagined is a simple fix like encode/ decode your results so you wont get the corrupted character...

Comment: It matters because there are a a thousand ways string encoding can be done and a thousand ways your assumptions could be wrong and a thousand ways to do it incorrectly, and they all depend on the exact circumstances you are in. For example *until now* it was not even clear that we are talking about JS code.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Turns out vscode cant read those chars but notepad can. A big thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: @peter VSCode can read those characters as well, trust me. This answer is based on wrong assumptions and does not really solve your question, you should not accept it. But you should learn that it's vital to include all information in a question, even if you don't think it's relevant. It could have saved both of us a lot of time.

Comment: @peter123 Look at my answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61478782). The encoding in your case is pretty much the same thing. You can adapt the answer to your situation.